# How do I escape a rift dimension?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Playing survival with the [Big Dig mod pack](http://technicpack.net/modpack/details/big-dig-pack.57), I made a rift door (from [Dimensional Doors](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1650007-151universal-dimensional-doors-v133-physics-what-physics/page__hl__%20tinkers%20%20explosion)) so I could have my own house/secret room type of thing. I've discovered that I'm trapped now. How do I get out?

Comment: In the video you posted about Dimensional doors, he showed the dimensional trapdoor. When he went in he went back to his top dimension. You could try and use that?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately i don't think there is a way out without following the corridor back the way you came, I'm still trying to figure this one out.

If you're really desperate though you could try opening the game to LAN with cheats enabled, typing `/gamerule keepInventory true` followed by `/kill` to try respawning at the spawn point along with all your items (the gamerule command stops you losing your items on death).

Unfortunately these worlds have a habit of changing your spawn point when you're inside the other dimension so you might be a touch screwed. I seem to remember spawning in some obsidian and building a portal to the nether though, Once i was inside i was able to build another portal and go through which generated an exit on the overworld (regular world) and i was able to escape. Only catch was i had to spawn in the actual Portal item that makes up the purple stuff on the inside `/give playername 90`

Give those a shot see how you get on :)

Answer (score 0):

I actually got out using the Rift Signature and I spawned in an ocean... I had to spawn it in though

Answer (score 0):

try making a nether portal then finding your old nether portal and/or making a new one that brings you into the over world.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get out of the dimension, dig to the very bottom and just fall there are some orange blocks that teleport you to the over world just a little farther away from home. Unfortunately I have not tried this out side of creative mode so please be careful.

Answer (score 0):

die,then escape limbo by finding the void

Answer (score 0):

use your rift blade to make the teleport 'hole' and go through that.  It brought me back to the over world.

Answer (score 0):

If you type slash help 2 (depends on the modpack, i was using roguelike adventures and dungeons) it comes up with aroma1997 commands. if you type /aroma1997 tp 0, it will teleport you back to the overworld!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I'm playing r.a.d and I bring a warp stone from way stones and teleport out if I ever get stuck. I've also got a void charm so I don't die.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, best plan of action to anyone out there stuck in another dimention is to die. This will make you spawn in limbo, there is some pretty scary stuff in there, but don't worry!
Then, make your way to these dark red blocks, they will be hard to see but you will find them eventually!
Hop onto set block and bob's your uncle, you are back in the overworld! A minor issue you will be ***Very*** far away from where you entered, so make sure you have a marker! I hope this helps, Rift Jumpers!